# Replacing null with empty string

Tags: karate

I want to replace all null values in an json with empty string and then compare the 2 json arrays.

eg.
json1:
[ {
"address01": "address1",
"address02": "address2",
"address03": null
},
{
"address01": "address1",
"address02": null,
"address03": null
}
]

json2:
[ {
"address01": "address1",
"address02": "address2",
"address03": ""
},
{
"address01": "address1",
"address02": "",
"address03": ""
}
]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
* def fun = function(x) { karate.forEach(x, function(k, v) { if (!v) x[k] = '' }); return x }
* def temp = karate.map(json1, fun)
```

Comment: getting the below error: javascript evaluation failed: karate.map(json1, fun), java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Comment: try upgrading. else please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue